# Checking if a number is an Integer in Java

Tags: java, utilities

Is there any method or quick way to check whether a number is an Integer (belongs to Z field) in Java?

I thought of maybe subtracting it from the rounded number, but I didn't find any method that will help me with this.

Where should I check? Integer Api?

Comment: You are parsing number from String or you already have number in some float or double?

Comment: What do you mean "belongs to Z field"?

Comment: I have any number, it can be float ir double as well.

Comment: Z field- It means that it is integer.

Comment: @ntt: N = natural numbers, Z = integer, Q = rational, R = real, C = complex

Comment: Z isn't a field, as far as I know. Are you using "field" in some other sense than the abstract math sense?

Comment: BTW: Is it possible to show the Unicode representations of those symbols here? Like U+2124 for Z?

Comment: Got it!! Thanks!.. So you have saved it as a float or something and wanna check if it's a 'whole number'?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Quick and dirty...

```
if (x == (int)x)
{
   ...
}
```

edit: This is assuming x is already in some other numeric form.  If you're dealing with strings, look into `Integer.parseInt`.

Comment: Normally I have a function isInteger(), which has try catch over Integer.parseInt, returning false in case exception is occurring.

Comment: this is a good answer, and I upvoted it for that reason -- but still, make sure you understand the limitations of floating point representations!

Comment: orginaly this solution dont work for me but it use it in this wary:
if (x.intValue() == x.doubleValue()) {}

Answer (score 18):

One example more :)

```
double a = 1.00

if(floor(a) == a) {
   // a is an integer
} else {
   //a is not an integer.
}
```

In this example, ceil can be used and have the exact same effect.

Answer (score 10):

```
/**
 * Check if the passed argument is an integer value.
 *
 * @param number double
 * @return true if the passed argument is an integer value.
 */
boolean isInteger(double number) {
    return number % 1 == 0;// if the modulus(remainder of the division) of the argument(number) with 1 is 0 then return true otherwise false.
}
```

Answer (score 4):

if you're talking floating point values, you have to be very careful due to the nature of the format.

the best way that i know of doing this is deciding on some epsilon value, say, 0.000001f, and then doing something like this:

```
boolean nearZero(float f)
{
    return ((-episilon < f) && (f <epsilon)); 
}
```

then

```
if(nearZero(z-(int)z))
{ 
    //do stuff
}
```

essentially you're checking to see if z and the integer case of z have the same magnitude within some tolerance. This is necessary because floating are inherently imprecise.

NOTE, HOWEVER: this will probably break if your floats have magnitude greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (2147483647), and you should be aware that it is by necessity impossible to check for integral-ness on floats above that value.

Comment: +1: You get round error on `float` for integers greater than 2^24 (about 16 million) If you use `double` you get round errors for integers gretaer than 2^53 (8 million trillion)

Answer (score 1):

With Z I assume you mean Integers , i.e 3,-5,77 not 3.14, 4.02 etc.

A regular expression may help:

```
Pattern isInteger = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
```

Comment: by Z he meant Integers, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer <-- Z is the normal symbol used to represent the set.

Comment: @notthetup - I don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

```
    double x == 2.15;

    if(Math.floor(x) == x){
        System.out.println("an integer");
    } else{
        System.out.println("not an integer");
    }
```

I think you can similarly use the `Math.ceil()` method to verify whether `x` is an integer or not. This works because `Math.ceil` or `Math.floor` rounds up `x` to the nearest integer (say `y`) and if `x==y` then our original `x' was an integer.

Answer (score 0):

change x to 1 and output is integer, else its not an integer add to count example whole numbers, decimal numbers etc.

```
   double x = 1.1;
   int count = 0;
   if (x == (int)x)
    {
       System.out.println("X is an integer: " + x);
       count++; 
       System.out.println("This has been added to the count " + count);
    }else
   {
       System.out.println("X is not an integer: " + x);
       System.out.println("This has not been added to the count " + count);


   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    if((number%1)!=0)
    {
        System.out.println("not a integer");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("integer");
    }
```

Comment: Be careful with floats and doubles in Java, their (lack of) precision can cause problems. Use BigDecimal

Comment: @PabloLozano I did not understand your concern, can you please explain your comment with some example.

Answer (score 0):

All given solutions are good, however most of them can give issues with Static Code Analysis (e.g. SONAR): "*Floating point numbers should not be tested for equality*" (see https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/RSPEC-1244).

I am assuming that input that should be tested is double, not string.

As a workaround, I test numbers for *not* being integers:

```
public boolean isNotInteger(double x) {
    return x - Math.floor(x) > 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 int x = 3;

 if(ceil(x) == x) {

  System.out.println("x is an integer");

 } else {

  System.out.println("x is not an integer");

 }
```

Comment: This pretty much repeats the top answers and without including the `ceil(int)` function, this is unusable. Also, if `x` is already an `int`, what point does this check even have?

Answer (score -1):

Check if ceil function and floor function returns the same value

```
static boolean isInteger(int n) 
{ 
return (int)(Math.ceil(n)) == (int)(Math.floor(n)); 
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can just use `x % 1 == 0` because x % 1 gives the residual value of x / 1

Comment: Similiar answers are already present, makes no sense posting it again.

Answer (score -3):

// in C language.. but the algo is same

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  float x = 77.6;

  if(x-(int) x>0)
    printf("True! it is float.");
  else
    printf("False! not float.");        

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Probably you should post it in a question explicitly targeted at C (e.g. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796983/checking-if-float-is-an-integer), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20068234/c-how-to-check-if-the-number-is-integer-or-float) )? Make sure that your approach doesn't repeat already posted answers.