# Semantic issue invalid operands to binary expression ('double' and 'double')

Tags: c++, binary, expression

I`m trying to divide any number in .5, if dividing the number in .5 and my remain is 0 the number will raises up to the next. But if not, it will down to the next.

When I try to do that I get a issue in the line 39. Somebody can help me.

Thanks

```
//
//  main.cpp
//  Promedio
//
//  Created by Oscar Espinosa on 3/27/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 IPN ESIME Ticoman. All rights reserved.
//

#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int ed, cv, qa, em, h, poo;
float prom, red;
string nom, ape;

cout << " Introduce tus datos" << endl
     <<"Nombre: ";
getline(cin, nom);
cout << "Apellidos: ";
getline(cin, ape);
cout << "Introduce las siguientes calificaciones" << endl
     << "Ecuaciones Diferenciales: ";
cin  >> ed ;
cout << "Calculo vectorial: ";
cin  >> cv ;
cout << "Quimica apilcada: ";
cin  >> qa ;
cout << "Electricidad y magnetismo: ";
cin  >> em;
cout << "Humanidades II: ";
cin  >> h;
cout << "Programacion orientada a objetos: ";
cin >> poo ;
prom = (ed+cv+qa+em+h+poo)/6.00;

if (prom%.5 == 0) // Semantic issue invalid operands to binary expression ('double' and 'double')
{
    ceil(prom);
    red = ceil(prom);
}
else
{
    floor(prom);
    red = floor(prom);
}

cout << nom << " " << ape << " tu promedio es " << prom << " y se redondea a " << red;

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

@Oscar Espinosa  
 you cannot use %(modulus) operator with double values 
So its showing the error invalid operands in expression..
  try using the `fmod(x,y)` function..it will work

Comment: excellent answer, didn't know about this function, upvoted :) But again, test equality to zero up to some small epsilon.

Answer (score 1):

Modulo (%) can only be used with integer values.
You can use fmod but if you meant to work on integer values, perhaps such a trick can help:

```
if (10*static_cast< int >(prom)%5 == 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is pretty clear: you don't define `var` before the `if(var==0)`. In C++, you need to define the variable before its first use. Pay attention to what the compiler is telling you. In case of g++:

> ```
> error: 'var' was not declared in this scope
> ```

which I think it's pretty explicit!

PS: don't modify the code after an answer, as you end up confusing everyone. In the actual code, you are passing `0.5` as the modulus operator argument. That operator takes an `int`. You need other way of testing whether a `float` is a multiple of `0.5`. In particular, you should also pay attention to roundoff errors.

Hint: a `float` `x` is a multiple of 0.5 if and only if `2*x` is an integer. So `2*x - floor(2*x)` must be close to zero, i.e. `abs(2*x - floor(2*x)) < 1e-12` to avoid floating point errors.

See related question: [Checking if float is an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5796983/3093378)