# Trying to create a C program which prints out all numbers with rational square roots?

Tags: c, cs50

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <math.h>

void rationalSquareRoots(void);

int main(void) {
    rationalSquareRoots();
}

void rationalSquareRoots(void) {
    for(float i = 0; ; i++) {
    if(sqrt(i) % 1 == 0) {
        printf("%f\n", i);
    }
    sleep(1);
    }
}
```

I've encountered the following problem while attempting to make a program which prints out all numbers with rational square roots (well, all numbers up to the point of overflowing, I guess).

```
14:19: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('double' and 'int')
    while(sqrt(i) % 1 == 0) {
```

The problem seems to be in the **%** operator? Is it not supported in `if` statements? What's the solution?

Comment: The `%` operatoris not supported for floating point values, which is what `sqrt` returns.

Comment: If you want modulo for floats, use fmod function. Also I recommend reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796983/checking-if-float-is-an-integer) thread.

Comment: You could start with rational numbers and print their squares...

Comment: Aside: never use the inferior `float` without a compelling reason why you can't use `double`. Note that `double sqrt(double x);` isn't using the `float` type.

Comment: Side note: your question says "all numbers with rational square roots", but your program is evidently trying to print numbers with *integral* square roots. 2.25 (aka 9/4) is an example of a number with a [rational](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_number) square root which isn't integral.

Comment: @SteveSummit And indeed, the _only_ numbers with rational square roots are those whose numerator and denominator are squares of integers (discarding 0 as a candidate for the denominator).

Comment: There are countably infinite numbers with rational square roots. Are you planning to print them all?

Comment: Numerical checking if number is rational is very complicated

Comment: In my first comment above, I should have clarified that the only numbers with rational square roots are those whose numerator and denominator **in their simplest form** are squares of integers. For example 8/18 has a rational square root but is not in its simplest form. (The simplest form is 4/9 and the rational square root is 2/3.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `%` operator is only for divisions between integers.

To calculate remainders of floating-point divisions, you should use [`fmod()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fmod.3p.html) function.

Using this function, the condition should be `fmod(sqrt(i), 1) == 0`.

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by the fact [the modulo (`%`) is defined only for integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102948/why-does-modulus-division-only-work-with-integers#:%7E:text=The%20modulo%20operator%20%25%20in%20C,this%20answer%20to%20receive%20notifications) in C and C++. `sqrt(i)` returns a `double` (which it should, as square roots of integers can have infinite decimal digits), hence causing an error.

You can totally do what you're doing here, with use of the [fmod](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fmod.3p.html) function instead.

However, I will also offer an alternative implementation which, in terms of time complexity, is much more efficient. Instead of iterating through the integers and checking if their square roots are rational, simply output the square numbers.

I understand that you may be doing this as a practice for the C operators (or practice for C in general), but maybe someone will find this useful.

```
void rationalSquareRoots(void) {
    for(float i = 0; ; i++) {
        printf("%f\n", i*i);
//        sleep(1);
          sleep((i+1)*(i+1)-i*i); //to give the same behaviour as your provided code
    }
}
```

Comment: `sleep((i+1)*(i+1)-i*i);` instead of `sleep(1);` may be better for compatibility.

Comment: @MikeCAT Thank you. I've added this to my answer.

Comment: thanks mate! I'm following the cs50 starter course online and the teacher man said that the best way to code is to develop your logic or something, so it wasn't the syntax itself which was important for beginners, but the way we approach problems. This was just my idea of doing so, but I appreciate your suggestion either way.

Comment: will it display result of `(3/7)*(3/7)`?

Comment: @0___________ No it won't. Nor will OP's code. If you've read OP's code sample, OP is referring to all integers with rational square roots.

Comment: @RyanZhang so this code makes no sense for floats

Comment: @0___________ what do you mean? Are you saying I should be using `int` instead? I used floats to match OP's `printf` statement.

Comment: OPs code is basically invalid and cannot be repaired - it has to be rewritten. The task is very complex