# Convert number string to smallest possible number type (int, long, double, ...)

Tags: c, string, parsing, numbers

I need to convert a string read from stdin and convert the string to the smallest possible number data type.

For example:
`25325` would be registered as a short.
`458685864532` will be read into a long.
`54515,52` will be registered as a float.
`48559,486236596` as a double.

I don't want to read the value into the biggest possible data type and then do some math to get the bit size needed and then convert it into the smallest. I was thinking to go through every char in a string and decide what to do.

For example a string that is 10 chars long and the first digit is 3 and there is no minus, it will automatically use unsigned int because it's bigger than a signed int and smaller than a long. (In this example I omitted the limits for the specific compiler.)

Comment: You must be using a 64-bit Unix machine for 458685864532 to be convertible to `long`.

Comment: Note that if the eighth character of your ten character string is a comma (decimal point), then it won't fit in an `unsigned int`.

Comment: Your last paragraph about assuming unsigned int is not quite correct; number could still be float. This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20069488/694733) is relevant.

Comment: "I don't want to read the value into the biggest possible data type and then do some math to get the bit size needed and then convert it into the smallest." - Why? It's the easiest way to do it. Convert first, then shrink, instead of mixing the two tasks.