# Is there a general format specifier for `sscanf`?

Tags: c, scanf, format-specifiers

I'm working with a C(++) program, who needs to read values from a file. Those values can be integers (signed or unsigned) or floating point numbers. At this moment the file only contains decimal numbers (integers), as a `sscanf()` format specifier `%d` seems to be sufficient.

However in future the file might contain all kinds of numbers, like positive or negative numbers (integers or floating point numbers) and in latter case, the precision is not known, neather the presence of leading or trailing zeroes, as in following examples:

```
1
+2
-34
12.5
-13.5
+00014.31000000
```

Is there a format specifier which can cover all those cases, or am I dreaming?

Thanks

Comment: You're dreaming.... use `fgets()`.

Comment: Provide the type of the value along with the value, or first check for a floating format, and if it fails, check for an interger.

Comment: for c++ you can use `cin << `

Comment: what data type of variable would this magic specifier store its result in?

Comment: Just use a floating-point specifier with a floating-point type. Floating-point types can hold integers after all.

Comment: @M.M You could put it into a union with a tag, with a custom parser.

Comment: @2501 useless unless you also have a way of knowing which type to read out...

Comment: @M.M Using types and unions usually comes with a tag, otherwise it wouldn't make sense.

Comment: Related: [C - How to check if the number is integer or float?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20069488/694733)

Comment: As far as the result type is concerned: the idea is to read it as a floating point number. In case the number is an integer, it can be converted afterwards.

Comment: This makes no sense. There is a real number that can be written as `1` or `1.0`. Both ways of writing it are perfectly OK. Incidentally you can also write an integer number as `1` but why should this have any relevance to your work with real numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there exists such a magic specifier, because you the type of arguments passed to `sscanf()` is fixed.

Regardless of the possible loss of precision, integers can be seen as floating point numbers (but no vice versa). So if you don't care whether the input is an integer or a floating point number, simply use `fgets(input, BUFFER_SIZE, stdin);` followed by `scanf(input, "%lf", &dblVal);`.

However, if you really care, here is an example on how to deal with them:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 80

int main(void)
{
    char *input = malloc(BUFFER_SIZE);
    char *endptr;
    fgets(input, BUFFER_SIZE, stdin);
    input[strcspn(input, "\n")] = '\0';

    long intVal = strtol(input, &endptr, 10);
    if(!*endptr)
    {
        // input is an integer
        printf("%ld", intVal);
    }
    else
    {
        // input is an floating point number
        double dblVal;
        int r, n;
        r = sscanf(input, " %lf%n", &dblVal, &n);
        if(r == 1 && n == strlen(input))
            printf("%g", dblVal);
        else
            puts("Invalid input");
    }
}
```