# Converting Strings from a .csv file to doubles

Tags: c, string, double, atof

Having trouble with the converting of strings to doubles.  I've tried using `strtod`, but that does the same thing. It seems like this should work just find but perhaps using `strtok` has something to do with it. `data[i].calories` is a double of course.

```
data[i].calories = atof(strtok(NULL, ","));
```

It seems to assign either a positive or negative really big number to calories (a double, which means it must be reading the value wrong.

Data Expected:

> 12cx7,23:55:00,->0.968900025,(this could also be a double),0,74,0,2,

What it instead actually gets:

> 12cx7,23:55:00,->-537691972,0,0,74,0,2,

EDIT:

IM AN IDIOT I WAS DISPLAYING IT AS AN INT PFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.

Comment: How are you displaying the double value? You do not use `"%d"`, do you?

Comment: How should we know what `data[i].calories` is or how you print the values? This is the reason why you should always add a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If you think, `strtok` might be involved in the problem, what did it show when you checked the results of `strtok`?

Comment: Please (re)read about how to make an MCVE ([MCVE]).  Note that this includes some sample input data (2 lines would be sufficient), the expected output and the actual output (if there is any; if the program crashes before generating output, say so).  Without that, all we can do is guess — you're quite possibly getting a null pointer from `strtok()`, for example.  Certainly, you should be capturing what `strtok()` returns and printing it (if it isn't null) to ensure that you're getting what you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming we have an input like this,

> 12cx7,23:55:00,0.968900025,,0,74,0,2,

And we would like to,

> *"Having trouble with the converting of strings to doubles."*

That is we would like to separate the alphanumeric data . And then the remaining ints and floats, we would like to print in the correct format, I would do something like the following:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int isNumeric (const char * s)
{
    if (s == NULL || *s == '\0' || isspace(*s)) {
      return 0;
    }
    char * p;
    strtod (s, &p);
    return *p == '\0';
}

bool isInteger(double val)
{
    int truncated = (int)val;
    return (val == truncated);
}

int main() {
    // If this is your input:
    char input[100] = "12cx7,23:55:00,0.968900025,0,74,0,2,";
    // Then step 1 -> we split the values
    char *token = std::strtok(input, ",");
    while (token != NULL) {
        // Step 2 -> we check if the values in the string are numeric or otherwise
        if (isNumeric(token)) {
            // printf("%s\n", token);
            char* endptr;
            double v = strtod(token, &endptr);
            // Step 3 -> we convert the strings containing no fractional parts to ints
            if (isInteger(v)) {
                int i = strtol(token, &endptr, 10);
                printf("%d\n", i);
            } else {
                // Step 4 -> we print the remaining numeric-strings as floats
                printf("%f\n", v);
            }
        }
        else {
            // What is not numeric, print as it is, like a string
            printf("%s,",token);
        }
        token = std::strtok(NULL, ",");
    }
}
```

For the `isInteger()` function, I took the idea/code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20068358/2955790) accepted answer. The rest is quite original and probably could be refined/improved.

This produces then this output:

> 12cx7,23:55:00,0.968900,0,74,0,2,

which is basically the output that we want, except with the very important difference that the input was a whole single string and the output is doubles/floats, ints and strings correctly identified and printed with the correct formatting.

**EDIT**:

I am not any doing error-handling here. This code is just to give the OP a proof-of-concept. Check and control for any errors returned from the used `strtoX` functions.

Comment: You should really avoid the `atoX` functions. They provide zero ability to validate the conversion. Instead using the `strtoX` functions, you have fine-grained control over error checking and validation of the conversion. (and yes, I know that was asked for in the question, but it is always helpful to ensure they know the difference)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Edited as per your suggestion. Yes, it was known to me that `atoX` functions are unsafe, but to provide a proof-of-concept (and not robust production-level code), I had used them here.

Comment: Well, that's better, but unless you are checking `if (token == endptr)` (to determine if digits were converted, and if so, `if (errno)` indicating over/underlfow occurred, you may as well use `atoX`. For the purpose of your question, I would just add a node under your code indicating that both should be checked for. (also you mixed your C++ with your C, e.g. `std::strtok` `:)` Also, why `strtod` instead of a `strchar (token, '.')`? Just seems a bit 'different' in the approach.