# How do i check the input is an integer in java

Tags: java, validation

In my program I want an integer input by the user. I want an error message to be show when user inputs a value which is not an integer.
And How can I do this in loop. i am just a beginner please help me.

```
        //code that i already try
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int age;
        String AGE ;


        System.out.print("\nEnter Age       : "); 
        AGE = input.nextLine();
        try{
          age = Integer.parseInt(AGE);

        }catch (NumberFormatException ex){

             System.out.print("Invalid input " + AGE + " is not a number");
        }
```

Comment: You are trying to input 100 ages?  Where is your attempt to loop?

Comment: oh i am sorry dont mean it to be an array it supposed to be just an int

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5502548/checking-if-a-number-is-an-integer-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use an while loop and break on sucess

```
int age;

while (true) {   // wil break on sucess 
   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.print("\nEnter Age       : "); 
   String AGE = input.nextLine();
    try{
      age = Integer.parseInt(AGE);
      break;  
    }catch (NumberFormatException ex){
        System.out.print("Invalid input " + AGE + " is not a number");
    }
}
```

Comment: To remove “unintentional” space, use AGE.trim()...

Answer (score 1):

This is the better way to check user input is integer or Not -

```
public static void onlyInteger() {


    int myInt = 0;
    System.out.println(" Please enter Integer");
    do {
        while (!input.hasNextInt()){
            System.out.println(" Please enter valid Integer :");
            input.next();
        }
        myInt = input.nextInt();
    }while (myInt  <= 0);

}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Works OK for negative ages, but ages can be 0, and also not very portable to other uses of wanting valid `int` input

Comment: yeh you are right I just gave him an idea to check valid int , he can manipulate or use his logic to print integers according to his use cases. Thanks :)

Comment: Why is myInt a double?

Comment: oh sorry my bad. I have updated the code :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to capture the age input as an integer, you would not need the integer array as such

'int age [] = new int [100];'

You can use Scanner's ***nextInt()*** method to capture integer input.

This will throw ***InputMismatchException*** exception in case the input is not an integer.Try below code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter Age: ");
        try {
            int number = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Age entered " + number);
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Incorrect Input for Age.Please enter integer Integer value");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does not answer the question

Answer (score 0):

To check the input is an *integer* or any *number* :

```
Step 1 is to Read the input as Java Object, then
```

```
Object o = new Integer(33);// or can be new Float(33.33)...

if(o instanceof Number) {
   System.out.println(o +" is number");// do your thing here
}
```

> The abstract class Number is the superclass of platform classes representing numeric values that are convertible to the primitive types byte, double, float, int, long, and short.

[JavaDoc Number](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html)